Python DFS Call Difference
I was trying to solve this leetcode problem involving DFS with Python: https://leetcode.com/problems/count-sub-islands/
This is my initial solution, which failed the test cases:
class Solution:

    def countSubIslands(self, grid1: List[List[int]], grid2: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        ans=0

        def dfs(i,j):
            if not (0<=i<len(grid1) and 0<=j<len(grid1[0]) and grid2[i][j]):
                return True
            if (not grid2[i][j] and grid1[i][j]) or (grid2[i][j] and not grid1[i][j]):
                return False
            if grid1[i][j] and grid2[i][j]:
                grid2[i][j] = 0
                return dfs(i+1,j) and dfs(i-1,j) and dfs(i,j+1) and dfs(i,j-1)
         
        for i in range(len(grid2)):
            for j in range(len(grid2[0])):
                if grid2[i][j] and dfs(i,j):
                    ans+=1
        return ans

However, when I split up the dfs calls in the return statement like this, the code worked:
class Solution:

    def countSubIslands(self, grid1: List[List[int]], grid2: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        ans=0

        def dfs(i,j):
            if not (0<=i<len(grid1) and 0<=j<len(grid1[0]) and grid2[i][j]):
                return True
            if (not grid2[i][j] and grid1[i][j]) or (grid2[i][j] and not grid1[i][j]):
                return False
            if grid1[i][j] and grid2[i][j]:
                grid2[i][j] = 0
                #return dfs(i+1,j) and dfs(i-1,j) and dfs(i,j+1) and dfs(i,j-1)
                one=dfs(i+1,j)
                two=dfs(i-1,j)
                three=dfs(i,j+1)
                four=dfs(i,j-1)
                return one and two and three and four

        for i in range(len(grid2)):
            for j in range(len(grid2[0])):
                if grid2[i][j] and dfs(i,j):
                    ans+=1
        return ans

Can someone explain to me the difference between the dfs calls, since they seem to be equivalent to me? Thank you!
I tried the first code snippet, which didn't work. After splitting up the dfs calls in the second snippet, it worked.

What does "didn't work" mean?

The test cases failed

This is caused by and's "short-circuiting" behavior, where the expression is evaluated left to right until it encounters a False value, after which it will stop evaluating that expression. When you separated out each of the dfs calls, the short-circuiting behavior was bypassed because each dfs call was executed before the and expression. But in your first code, the short-circuiting behavior of and would cause some dfs calls to not be made, making your function incorrect.
For example, if it were to happen that dfs(i+1,j) returned a False value, then evaluation of the and expression will immediately stop there and dfs(i-1,j), dfs(i,j+1) and dfs(i,j-1) will not be called.
